# What's Vasquez's first name?

Tags: alien-franchise, aliens-1986

> "[I only need to know one thing…](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8njXfB3-fi8)"

And that thing is... **what's Private Vasquez' first name?**

I can't seem to find it in any cast listing. Ripley & Hicks's first names got revealed in the special edition but as for the others.. *who knows?*

Comment: It’s Jenette…it’s on the wiki page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The in-universe factbook [The Weyland-Yutani Report](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Alien:_The_Weyland-Yutani_Report) names her as

> **Jenette** Vasquez

[image: Spanish copy of the Weyland-Rutani Report]
<sub><sup>[image courtesy of Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_Rx4Hxxjbk&feature=youtu.be&t=2m52s)</sup></sub>

---

In case you're interested, the rest of the [crew of the Sulaco](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Sulaco#Crew) were [*Lance*](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Lance_Bishop#cite_note-8) Bishop, *Scott* Gorman, *Dwayne* Hicks, *Trevor* Wierzbowski, *William* Hudson, *Al* Apone, *Cynthia* Dietrich, *Mark* Drake, *Ricco* Frost, *Tim* Crowe, *Colette* Ferro and *Daniel* Spunkmeyer. Company representative *Carter* Burke and civilian adviser *Ellen* Ripley were also in attendance (joined later by *Rebecca* "Newt" Jorden).

Comment: Where did you find that picture? I was looking for it. Do you have the book?

Comment: @Adamant - Youtube is your friend. This copy is in Spanish but it's the same in the [English version](https://youtu.be/kPc-ubcHZtk?t=10m46s), just not as clear

Comment: Based on the information on those wiki pages, it looks like the first names of the characters who didn't have their first names mentioned in the script come from the first names of the actors.  They match for Vasquez, Apone, Bishop, Dietrich, Drake, and Ferro (and possibly others; I stopped checking after finding enough to rule out coincidence.)